# How to get better bevels?

Tags: mesh, bevel

as someone who is coming from modo it's frustrating to use blender's bevels:

[image: Wtf is this]

It can be better if we somehow will bevel **concave** first:
[image: Concave bevel]

And then bevel **convex**:
[image: Convex bevel]

All of the above goes to Bevel modifier also.

BTW modo got new powerful options to bevel tool in last update :
https://vimeo.com/241009931

If only someone could help with moving it into blender D:

Comment: Could you specify what the question is about? Are you asking in which ways can the software be improved, where to look in the source code for the bevel or something about how to use the tool itself to obtain a certain shape?

Comment: I'm curious about ways to get better bevels.

Maybe there are custom bevel tools or modifiers, or there are some experimental branches with better bevels.

Current tool has almost no options to tweak, so i'ts pointless to ask about it :(

Comment: How about you try google. I mean really.

Comment: How about you give actual answer? I mean really.

I did googled, i talked to creator of hardOps and he doesn't know also.